# Mark json schema field as required for required xml tags

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I generate JSON schema from XSD in a way like this:
https://dzone.com/articles/generating-json-schema-xsd

Everything works fine except but it doesn't mark fields as required for those tags from XSD which mark as required (or minOccurs="1").
Is it possible to do with Jackson library?
Or some other tool?

I need something this:

```
{
"type": "object",
"required": true,
"properties": {
    "field": "value" ...
```

Comment: The only option I know is to set @JsonProperty(required = true). But my goal is to generate JSON Schema in the code, without modifying POJO manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is an answer.
You just have to register new JaxbAnnotationModule in your ObjectMapper instance.
Here is a code snippet:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.factories.SchemaFactoryWrapper;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);

    //To force mapper to include JAXB annotated properties in Json schema
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    objectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(objectMapper.constructType(YOUR_JAXB_CLASS.class), visitor);

    JsonSchema inputSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    String schemaString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inputSchema);

    System.out.println(schemaString);
```